# How to write a non-blocking method in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, nonblocking

I want to write a method that does not block. The method doesn't return anything.
This is not over the web or anything - its all local to the device it is running on.

Basically, the calling method just wants some other object to take care of something. And once it tells it "Go do this", the caller wants to get back to doing its own work instead of waiting for the object to finish executing the task.

I don't want to use NSNotification.

EDIT: I want to be able to do this using frameworks available on iOS 3.1.2 and later

EDIT: Thanks for all the great replies - but I am unsure about which to choose. My requirements are simply that the calling method be able to send arguments to the called method, and return immediately without waiting for the result. Which would be the best solution?

Comment: Why don't you want to use NSNotification (not that it helps you in this situation at all!)

Comment: I don't want to use NSNotification, as it is synchronous. NSNotificationQueue is a possibility, I don't have much experience with it, and was wondering if Objective-c has asynchronous or non-blocking methods which abstract away all the thread management etc.

Comment: Do you mean NSOperation? There is no such thing as NSNotificationQueue but NSOperationQueue exists :) And NSOperations running in an NSOperation queue are non-blocking.

Comment: I meant NSNotificationQueue - It is used if you want notifications to be non-blocking.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html I guess I should spend some time trying out NSOperation as well as the other suggestions. There are a lot of good answers and I need to understand them better to see which would work best for me. :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use one of: libdispatch, NSOperation, add an NSInvocation or 'perform selector on thread' to a run loop, create a thread...

**Update**

It depends on the time and complexity of what you want to do. If it's rather simple (e.g. simple text parsing), then just add it to the main run loop. If it takes more time (e.g. a download or opening a file), then you will want it off the main run loop.

**Create a thread**

You can use `pthread`s interfaces to create one or more threads to perform your work.

One might choose pthreads for the greatest performance and control of any option in the list. Regarding performance: It requires that you will understand costs and the problems well. Creating threads is not trivial, so it's good to reuse them or divide tasks well. Making and testing concurrent designs also takes a good amount of time.

*Personally*, I use a more portable abstraction (over pthreads, specifically) for most of my multithreading needs. If portability is important, then you'll likely want to use such an abstraction layer because the remainder of the options are not really seen outside of Apple's systems.

You could also use something like `-[NSObject performSelectorInBackground:withObject:]` for convenience with objc types.

**libdispatch**

(a.k.a. GCD)

Although I read it not an option for you, I'll write a brief overview regardless: Can be likened to a task/scheduler/thread pool abstraction layer over pthreads. This library is often used for concurrent tasks. It uses thread pooling for tasks, which may block or run asynchronously. Rather fast and simple abstraction, and easy to use.

**NSOperation**

Task (NSOperation) / pool+scheduler (NSOperationQueue) based interface which now uses libdispatch. This *feels* more task focused than libdispatch. It preceded libdispatch, and has an ObjC interface. There is, however, a lot of overlap in functionality. Rather fast and simple abstraction, and easy to use.

**Add an NSInvocation or 'perform selector on thread' to a run loop**

If your task is simple, you may want to use this low overhead approach of simply telling an object to perform a selector or an NSInvocation on a particular thread. The system will add it to the list of things to do (for the specified thread's run loop).

Having read your updates and comments and not knowing the time/complexity your specific problem, I'd suggest `NSOperation`. `pthread`s are pretty complex, and you should favor pooling over spawning threads whenever you need something to be performed asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems that there are a lot of good answers. I'm having a hard time trying to determine which one makes the most sense to use. Basically, I just want to target method to not block the calling method and do its business with minimum fuss.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few useful methods on NSObject that can help you - this one probably the most :

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doStuff) withObject:nil];


- (void)doStuff {
    // Do whatever you want to do here. It's in the background.
}
```

However, that assumes that you don't want to cancel your background task - you should also look at [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) if you need more control.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain what you mean about canceling the background task? Basically, I want the calling thread to continue executing after it kicks off the other task, without waiting for the task to finish. THanks.

Comment: What if you started something in the background and then decided that you didn't need it anymore - how would you stop it? (I don't know what your background task is going to do so you might not need the ability to cancel it)

Comment: In that case, sublcass NSOperation to do your background tasks and take a look at isCancelled lots :) - this seems to be a good tutorial : http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/

Answer (score 2):

I would use [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I neglected to mention, that I want to do this with iOS 3.1.2. ={ GCD sounds good, but a lot of the methods are available only on iOS 4.0 and later only.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSThread`'s `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`.

Answer (score 0):

This little peach worked for me (in-order to delay for 20 seconds)....

```
CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 20.0, false);
```